# Почему не меняется Effect Distance в Shadow unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
public class Decoration : MonoBehaviour {

    public Shadow block1Shadow;

    public void TopLineClick()
    {
        block1Shadow.effectDistance.Set(5f, 5f);
    }
}
```

Навесил метод на кнопку, но при нажатии ничего не происходит, остаются прежние значения, почему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как изменять effectDistance через код?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А не смущает, что `effectDistance` свойство, а результат структура `Vector2`?

```
var effectDistance = block1Shadow.effectDistance;
effectDistance.x = 5f;
effectDistance.y = 5f;
block1Shadow.effectDistance = effectDistance;
```

Или

```
block1Shadow.effectDistance = new Vector2(5f, 5f);
```